# aggregating sql tables in a query by distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in sql

```
order_table (order_id, product_id, amount)
```

```
products_table (product_id, name, price_usd),
```

```
all_orders (order_id, customer_id, order_date, total_amount),
```

I would like to produce a sql query which outputs the total revenue for each product by month for the last 12 months.

I somehow need to seperate out the distinct products, but I am not sure how to construct such a query.

any pointers would be great

Comment: For starters, determine if this is pgsql or mysql. You mention pgsql, but you tagged mysql. They are different dbms'. Providing sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @Isolated I have corrected it..

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804997/724039) given is using a `WITH....`, which is not needed:

```sql
select 
   DATE_FORMAT(all_orders.order_date, '%Y-%m') as order_date, 
   name as product_name, 
   sum(total_amount) as total_quantity, 
   sum(price_usd * total_amount) as total_revenue 
from all_orders
LEFT JOIN order_table USING (order_id)
LEFT JOIN products_table USING (product_id)
where all_orders.order_date >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 12 month)
group by 1,2 ;
```

should do the same (untested)

Comment: could you please say what `group by 1,2` is doing please? I would prefer to learn than blind c&p. would really appreciate your explanation

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2` is grouping on the columns 1 and 2.  (In this case `order_date` and `product_name`)

Comment: @user1191247:  Corrected this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `base_table` first in which it contain all necessary columns. you can use CTE to create to create this using `with`. After that, you can sum the column you wish  and end it using **where date >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 12 month)**

the general query is as follow :

```
with base as (SELECT
  all_orders.order_id,
  date_trunc(all_orders.order_date,month) as order_date,
  all_orders.total_amount as quantity
  name as product_name,
  price_usd * total_amount as revenue
FROM
  all_orders
LEFT JOIN
  order_table
USING
  (order_id)
LEFT JOIN 
  products_table 
USING 
  (product_id))

select order_date, product_name, sum(total_amount) as total_quantity, sum(revenue) as total_revenue from base 
where order_date >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 12 month)
group by 1,2
```

*Do note that I'm using Google SQL Dialect. It might be a little bit different in the dialect that you are currently using*

Comment: Which should give the same result as:  `select 
   date_trunc(all_orders.order_date,month) as order_date, 
   name as product_name, 
   sum(total_amount) as total_quantity, 
   sum(price_usd * total_amount) as total_revenue 
from all_orders
LEFT JOIN order_table USING (order_id)
LEFT JOIN products_table USING (product_id))
where all_orders.order_date >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 12 month)
group by 1,2 ;`

Comment: @Luuk if you could post this as an answer id be glad to accept it please

Comment: @AJW: posted it.